# Question about command line's delay and array

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So, I use command to load robots/ground by this line:

`ign service -s /world/free_world/create --reqtype ignition.msgs.EntityFactory --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --timeout 300 --req 'sdf_filename: ''"models/sdf/new_ground.sdf" pose: {position: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}} ''name: "ground_%s" ''allow_renaming: true'`

SO if I ran this with a loop, each line takes one second to load approximately. So, it seems that it has a delay. Is there any way to reduce the delay?

Also, is there a way to load more than 5 models at once?

Like for example:
`ign service -s /world/free_world/create --reqtype ignition.msgs.EntityFactory --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --timeout 300 --req 'sdf_filename: ''"model1.sdf, model2.sdf,model3.sdf" 'pose: {position: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},{x: 2, y: 0, z: 0},{x: 4, y: 0, z: 0}} '`

Obviously, above is just guess or psuedo command line. Is there any official command for it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28188/question-about-command-line%27s-delay-and-array/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My first guess as to the delay is likely due to transport discovery. Each time you run the command gazebo's transport has to find the service.

You can send a batch request using the `/world/WORLD_NAME/create_multiple` service. In your example it would look like:

```
ign service -s /world/free_world/create_multiple --reqtype gnition.msgs.EntityFactory_V --reptype ignition.msgs.Boolean --timeout 2000 --req 'data{MODEL1_INFOMATION} data{MODEL2_INFORMATION} data{MODEL3_INFORMATION}'
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2022-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-06-02**:
This answered my questions, thank you so much!

Last question if you don't mind! What about remove? I couldn't find remove_multiple